# MongoDB Join Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having the collections with below document structure.

****Collection-1 : getallusers:****

```
   db.getallusers.find().pretty()
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0c73e5930dd43c05ac221"),
            "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
            "userName" : "EPS Purecloud Support",
            "divisionId" : "36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
            "divisionName" : "",
            "emailId" : "eps@genesys.com",
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0c73e5930dd43c05ac222"),
            "userRefID" : "c5ce06dc-6265-4d16-be18-f5fc5a918295",
            "userName" : "Generic",
            "divisionId" : "36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
            "divisionName" : "",
            "emailId" : "integration-generic-a03293c0-945d-11ea-a64c-ebeb45b9d295@webhook.com",
            "__v" : 0
    }
```

**Collection-2 : getallusersroles:**

```
 db.getallusersroles.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0fb02b21b1d0760f3107b"),
        "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
        "skillRefId" : "c02dbb03-ed78-442a-a9cd-0f16c823646b",
        "queueName" : "CIM_test",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0fb02b21b1d0760f3107c"),
        "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
        "skillRefId" : "a626d99e-f5e9-47ab-a5d0-d493003c737f",
        "queueName" : "CLAIMS",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0fb02b21b1d0760f3107d"),
        "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
        "skillRefId" : "9b31524c-b574-4917-b470-8b86f430beaa",
        "queueName" : "CSS_AZ_IND_BILL_EN_1",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0fb03b21b1d0760f310b3"),
        "userRefID" : "c5ce06dc-6265-4d16-be18-f5fc5a918295",
        "skillRefId" : "f3bf0897-1b63-4a03-9f8f-5b18fc03401b",
        "queueName" : "Aflac",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ff0fb03b21b1d0760f310b4"),
        "userRefID" : "c5ce06dc-6265-4d16-be18-f5fc5a918295",
        "skillRefId" : "c02dbb03-ed78-442a-a9cd-0f16c823646b",
        "queueName" : "CIM_test",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

**Requirement:**

Need a collection 3 - testalluser as like below format:
Here in both collection , i am trying to join using "userRefID".
For me i need to add "role" as like below structure , could you please help me here. Thanks

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fdb245b848fbb32e86172c6"),
        "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
        "userName" : "EPS Purecloud Support",
        "divisionId" : "36852a81-ad7f-4c71-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
        "divisionName" : "",
        "emailId" : "eps@genesys.com",
       
         "roles":[{
                   "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
                   "skillRefId" : "c02dbb03-ed78-442a-a9cd-0f16c823646b",
                   "queueName" : "CIM_test"
                   },
                   {
                    "userRefID" : "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
                    "skillRefId" : "a626d99e-f5e9-47ab-a5d0-d493003c737f",
                    "queueName" : "CLAIMS",
                     }
                     {
                      ** third**
                     }                    
         
        "__v" : 0
    }
    {
    ** Similarly for second user data
    }
```

Below logic working correctly:

```
 db.getallusers.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "getallusersroles",
      "localField": "userRefID",
      "foreignField": "userRefID",
      "as": "role"
    }
  },
  
{ $merge: { into: "testalluser" } }

]).pretty()
```

Here i am creating testalluser collection  on the fly, not via Mongoose Model.

**Few queries:**

1.Each time, when  i execute this , i need to empty out all documents inside this collection and save the fresh documents in to it.
(Normally when i create the collection via Mongoose Model then i will use deleteMany({})by reference that Model to clear the data, but i am unable to do it here , as i didn't have model for this collection)

2.Whether its compulsory to create a Model for all collection , when i am using Mongoose.  Kindly correct me , thanks.

In below Nodejs(Mongoose)code , i am trying to delete this collection's documents and then need to perform this join logic to store the output in this collection(testalluser). Later i need to find and send as the response.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const config = require('../config');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const getAllUsers = require ('../db/getAllUsersListmodel');
const getAllUsersRoles = require ('../db/getetUserRolesListModel');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect ('mongodb://localhost/testdb',{ useUnifiedTopology: true , useNewUrlParser: true });

 
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // token in session -> get user data and send it back to the Angular app
   
  getAllUsersRoles.deleteMany({},()=>{  

    getAllUsersRoles.find((err,getusers)=>{
      if(err){
      console.log(err)
      }
      else{ 
        res.send(getusers);
        console.log(getusers);
      }
   })  
    
  })
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

Comment: change the  `"localField": "userId", "foreignField": "userId",` to `"localField": "userRefID",      "foreignField": "userRefID",`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pipeline within `$lookup` to get the desired output.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "roles",
      "let": {
        "users_userrefid": "$userRefID"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$userRefID",
                "$$users_userrefid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            __v: 0,
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "roles"
    }
  }
])
```

Here's a solution - https://mongoplayground.net/p/hXEavgJg_ek. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Varman. Thanks its my spellcheck issue, i corrected now in question. Currently i have to apply this logic using Mongoose in NodeJS , but i am facing few issues,could you guys help me here.